# What is the error in the following angularjs code?

Tags: angularjs

```
<html ng-app>

<body >

<div ng-controller="SimpleController">

     Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"> 
 </br>
 {{name}}


 </br>

    <ul  >
        <li ng-repeat="p in customers |filter:name | orderBy:'name'">{{p.name|uppercase }} .{{p.city}}
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

<script >
function SimpleController($scope){

    $scope.customers=[
    {name:'Apu',city:'jsr'},
    {name:'Gapu',city:'gujarat'},
    {name :'Papu', city:'gIndia'}
    ]
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's what you should tell us. What is the error? What do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead? It seems you learnt Angular with a tutorial written with Angular 1.0. But we're now at 1.5.8, and a lot has changed since then. Read the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably check your angularjs version, for above 1.3 versions global controller is not supported.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("SimpleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
  $scope.customers=[
    {name:'Apu',city:'jsr'},
    {name:'Gapu',city:'gujarat'},
    {name :'Papu', city:'gIndia'}
    ]
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
 <ul  >
        <li ng-repeat="p in customers |filter:name | orderBy:'name'">{{p.name|uppercase }} .{{p.city}}
        </li>
    </ul>
     
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```